# Could not find a required file index.html - Heroku push error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, heroku

I am pushing the react-node app to Heroku using Heroku CLI.

build is failing and the error is Could not find a required file index.html

I have checked all the files and everything in place

don't know what am I missing?

I am stuck here for one week.

Please help me

---

I am pushing the react-node app to Heroku using Heroku CLI.

build is failing and the error is Could not find a required file index.html

I have checked all the files and everything in place

don't know what am I missing?

I am stuck here for one week.

Please help me

```
Package.json
"main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

**Error :**

```
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 398 bytes | 398.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.9.4
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.2.0
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.9.4...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.9.4...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 6.2.0 (replacing 5.6.0)...
remote:        npm 6.2.0 installed
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        - node_modules
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        audited 2601 packages in 4.802s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:
remote:        > devconnector@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_cb13714e30f186bd579e6f8f21bf9383
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
remote:
remote:
remote:        > jss@9.8.7 postinstall /tmp/build_cb13714e30f186bd579e6f8f21bf9383/client/node_modules/jss
remote:        > node -e "console.log('\u001b[35m\u001b[1mLove JSS? You can now support us on open collective:\u001b[22m\u001b[39m\n > \u001b[34mhttps://opencollective.com/jss/donate\u001b[0m')"
remote:
remote:        Love JSS? You can now support us on open collective:
remote:         > https://opencollective.com/jss/donate
remote:
remote:        > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_cb13714e30f186bd579e6f8f21bf9383/client/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
remote:        > node lib/post_install.js
remote:
remote:        added 1375 packages from 852 contributors and audited 13755 packages in 46.845s
remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
remote:
remote:
remote:        > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_cb13714e30f186bd579e6f8f21bf9383/client
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:
**remote:        Could not find a required file.
remote:          Name: index.html**
remote:          Searched in: /tmp/build_cb13714e30f186bd579e6f8f21bf9383/client/public
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build scr`enter code here`ipt.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.bspBQ/_logs/2018-10-14T10_57_59_194Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! devconnector@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR!
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the devconnector@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.bspBQ/_logs/2018-10-14T10_57_59_208Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     **Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.**
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to murmuring-depths-54253.
```

Comment: Hopefully this will help you https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#user-content-quick-start

Comment: Having a similar issue locally. Moved my node_modules and package.json out of client location.

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered this issue today and managed to fix it by removing /public folder from .gitignore.

Two things could be cause of this:

1. Probably you have `/public` directory specified inside your `.gitignore`
2. Case sensitive paths

more info at: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#heroku

Answer (score 2):

*Possible Solution: Your file structure might be the issue*

By chance do you have an 'api' folder next to your 'client' folder?

- Heroku doesn't seem to play well with certain file structures (not sure why, I opened a ticket with them to inquire)
- I was receiving almost the exact same error because I had most of my 'server' files within an api folder at the root.
- After moving those files outside the api folder, removing my lock files, and reinstalling node modules, deployment went off without a hitch.

So, try the following:

1. Make sure that your file structure isn't conflicting with standard deployments (see screenshot below)
2. Remove your lock files and node_modules
3. Reinstall node_modules at root and in client
4. commit and and attempt another deploy -- let us know if that succeeds

As you can see, the only difference is the location of those folders within the api folder (obviously, import/require pathnames needed to be updated as well)

***Failing Folder Structure***

[image: This file structure fails with the same error message]

***Successful Folder Structure***

[image: This file structure succeeds as expected]