# Error when deploying Django-React app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, heroku

I'm deploying my Django-backend, React-frontend app to Heroku and when running `git push heroku master` I'm running into a weird error:

> Could not find a required file.
> Name: index.html
> Searched in:
> /tmp/build_7abd977a/public

Apparently when running `npm run build` it creates a `build` folder with the following structure:

[image]

Looks like for some reason the **public** folder isn't created upon running the scripts, can someone advice how can I perhaps create it with the script or run my **index.html** from a different location (Or at least tell me the location of the file its being imported in)?

Here is the full traceback:

[image]

Comment: First try running `python manage.py collectstatic` locally to verify that you are able to collect all the static files. Heroku does that.

Comment: give this a try https://stackoverflow.com/a/59575383/6562458

Comment: neither worked but thank you

Comment: @SLDem Could you add any more of the error. Is there anything that comes before it? What stage of the build is it in whilst this error is displayed?

Comment: @tim-mccurrach I've added the traceback after installing `node_modules`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57371378/5412278

Comment: @AppleJam already tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by moving my **portfolio-frontend** contents into the root of the project and then running `npm run build` again.